# Is there a way to see more details in commit history when using the GitHub web UI?

Tags: github

On a url like `https://github.com/{org}/{repo}/commits/main` you see a list of commits, I'd like to see more details of each commit on that same page, is that possible in the web UI?

To be extra clear: I know that I can see more commit info if I click through to the page of the commit, but I want to see more info on the page that shows the **list** of recent commits.

Are there extensions that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

All details of the commit are available right there on the Commits page (example from `rust-embedded/cross`):

[image: github screenshot]

This shows from top left to bottom right:

- Commit message
- Committer username
- Commit date (and if you hover over it, the exact time stamp)
- If checks/builds were ok after this commit
- If the commit was signed (and if you click it, with which specific key)
- The shortened commit hash (and if you click it, it shows you the diff between this commit and the previous commit)
- A link to the full repository at that time of the commit.

I'm not sure what more you can ask for, that is all the information that's available in Git about the commit.

Edit: When you click the commit message, it shows everything about the commit:

[image]

Comment: I can see the details that are *currently* there, of course :-) I'd like to see more details like full commit message, a list of changed files, amount of code and the amount of additions and deletions.

Comment: You can click the commit message and go to the commit page? It shows everything you ask for. See edit.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify.